# Meteor Forms Not Submitting

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm building a form system in Meteor and currently the forms are not submitting. I have followed the tutorials pretty closely. Unsure what the problem is. Here is the code for one of the forms. This form is for creating and submitting a "text" item.

```
<template name="CreateText">
<form id="CreateTextForm" class="Text" method="post">

<!-- Text Image -->
<input type="file" accept='image/*' id="TextImage" name=”ImageFileText” placeholder="Add an Image">

<!-- Text Date -->
{{getDate}}
<button type="button" id="textdate">CHANGE DATE</button>

<!-- Text Location -->
{{getLocation}}
<button id="textlocation" type=”button” name="LocationText"         value=”Location”>LOCATION</button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">    </span>

<!-- Text Creators -->
<div colspan="4" name="CreatorText" id="userviacreate">{{getName Meteor.userId}}</div>
{{currentUser.username}}

<!-- Text Collaborators -->
<div id="TextMembers">
  {{> esAutosuggest id="TextMembersAdd" name="CollaboratorsText"     index="collaborators" placeholder="Add a Member" renderValue="blank"     renderSuggestion="suggestionTpl"}}
  {{#each collaborators}} {{>collabTag}} {{/each}}
    </div>
<hr id="first">

<!-- Text Title -->
<input type="text" id="TextTitle" name="TitleText" placeholder="Add a Title.">

<!--Text Tags -->
  <div id="addtags">
    <input type="text" id="TextTags" name="TagsText" placeholder="Tag This">
    <button id="btn btn-default" type="button">Tag</button>
  </div>
  <hr class="second">

<!-- Text Text -->
 <textarea id="TextText" name="TextText" placeholder="Add Text..."></textarea>
  <div id="displaytags">
        {{ #each tags }} {{>textTag}} {{ /each }}
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Create Text Button -->
  <input id="createtext" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="CREATE">
</template>



And the accompanying JavaScript:

    Template.CreateText.events({
    'submit #CreateTextForm': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var textimagefile = event.target.ImageFileText.value;
        var texttitle = event.target.TitleText.value;
        var textText = event.target.TextText.value;
        var imagescreators = event.target.CreatorsImages.value;
        var textcreator = event.target.CreatorText.value;
        var textlocation = event.target.LocationText.value;
        var textdate = event.target.DateText.value;
        var texttags =  event.target.TagsText.value;

        Texts.insert ({
            ImageFileText: textimagefile,
            TitleText: texttitle,
            TextText: textText,
            CreatorsText: Meteor.userId(),
            CreatorsImages: imagescreators,
            LocationText: textlocation,
            DateText : new Date(),
            TagsText: texttags
        });

        event.target.TitleText.value = "";
        event.target.TextText.value = "";

        return false;
    }
});
```

***NEW***

```
// NEW BUTTON

<button id="createtext" class="btn btn-success"         value="PUBLISH">PUBLISH</button>

// PUBLISH AND SUBSCRIBE 

Texts = new Mongo.Collection("texts");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish("texts", function () {
    return Texts.find();
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
 // This code only runs on the client
 Meteor.subscribe("texts");
}

// ADJUSTED INSERT FUNCTIONS

Template.CreateText.events({
    'click #createtext': function(event) {
    /*
    var textimagefile =
    var texttitle = ;
    var textText = ;
    var imagescreators = ;
    var textcreator = ;
    var textlocation = ;
    var textdate = ;
    var texttags =  ;
    */
                    Texts.insert ({
                        /*
                        ImageFileText: $('#ImageFileText').val(),
                        CreatorsText: $("#CreatorsImages").val(),
                        CreatorsImages: $("#CreatorText").val(),
                        LocationText: $("#LocationText").val(),
                        DateText : $("#DateText").val(),
                        TagsText: $("#TagsText").val()
                        */
                        TitleText: $("#TitleText").val(),
                        TextText: $("#TextText").val(),

                    });
                    }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is outside of your `<form></form>` tags.  Putting the submit before your `</form>` tag should fix your problem unless there are further issues with your code that I have yet to see.

Comment: did that and it did not fix it. Every database query simply returns [ ] .

Comment: Nope nothing is working. I changed the code around a bit. Here it is:

Comment: I changed the button to this: <button id="createtext" class="btn btn-success" value="PUBLISH">PUBLISH</button>                         and changed the submit event to a click event......  Template.CreateText.events({
 'click #createtext': function(event) {
 
      Texts.insert ({
       TitleText: $("#TitleText").val(),
       TextText: $("#TextText").val(),

      });
      }
      });

Comment: and explicitly published and subscribed again...Texts = new Mongo.Collection("texts");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish("texts", function () {
    return Texts.find();
  });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
 // This code only runs on the client
 Meteor.subscribe("texts");
}

Comment: Still nothing...I realize this isn't the best medium of exchange.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console when you click submit?  Maybe you need to set up your allow/deny rules

Comment: Hmm that could very well be it. There are a few errors related to fonts (assume not the issue), and "Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41" "TypeError: Cannot read property 'limit' of undefined" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined" .